# Nightwatchjs - return a value from browser.getCookie()

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, nightwatch.js

I am quite new to JavaScript Programming and would like little help in understanding how I can proceed in this case:

Code :

```
var cookieName = 'myCookieName:';
var cookieValue = browser.getcookie('myCookieName', function(response){ 
console.log(response.value);
return response.value;
});
var cookieString = cookieName + cookieValue;
```

That is what I intend to do, but cookieValue is always undefined, however console.log(response.value) -> prints out the correct value :(

Answer (score 0):

Returning from a callback doesn't mean the caller function will also return the same value, it doesn't work like that - browser.getCookie() will always return undefined.

If you need to use the value of the cookie then you need to do it from within the callback function.

```
var cookieName = 'myCookieName:';
browser.getcookie(cookieName , function(response){ 
console.log(response.value);
// do what you need to do with the cookie - maybe call another function to process it, for example
processCookieValue(response.value);
});
```